# DB connections increase after setting aurora in MariaDB connector

Tags: jdbc, mariadb, slick, hikaricp, amazon-aurora

We're testing the failover behaviour using the MariaDB JDBC connector Aurora specific features.

We've set the JDBC URL as [the documentation suggest](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/failover-and-high-availability-with-mariadb-connector-j/):

```
jdbc:mysql:aurora://cluster.cluster-xxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/db
```

The problem is that as soon as we add the `aurora:` part in the URL schema, we can see an increase in the connections to the database writer until the point that we've to rollback the change (it even reaches 3.000 connections).

Versions:

- [MariaDB connector: 2.0.1](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.mariadb.jdbc%7Cmariadb-java-client%7C2.0.1%7Cjar)
- [HikariCP connection pool: 2.6.1](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.zaxxer%7CHikariCP%7C2.6.1%7Cbundle)
- [Play-Slick: 2.1.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.typesafe.play%7Cplay-slick_2.11%7C2.1.0%7Cjar)
- [Slick: 3.2.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.typesafe.slick%7Cslick_2.11%7C3.2.0%7Cbundle)

Configuration:

```
master {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
  db {
    driver = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
    url = "jdbc:mysql:aurora://cluster-name.cluster-xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/db_name?characterEncoding=utf8mb4&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&usePipelineAuth=false"
    user = "rw_user"
    password = "rw_user_pass"
    numThreads = 20
    queueSize = 1000000
  }
}
slaves = [
  {
    profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
    db {
      driver = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
      url = "jdbc:mysql:aurora://cluster-name.cluster-ro-xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/db_name?characterEncoding=utf8mb4&usePipelineAuth=false"
      user = "ro_user"
      password = "ro_user_pass"
      numThreads = 20
      queueSize = 1000000
    }
  }
]
```

We'd tried to add the `aurora:` part to the JDBC URL schema after upgrading the MariaDB connector version, but the number of connections to the Reader started to increase again:

[image]

If we run a `show processlist` on the read only endpoint, we can see all the opened connections in "cleaned up" state, and "Sleep" command.

We'd removed the `aurora:` part from the read only endpoint just in order to stabilize the number of connections to it. Is it possible that the driver searches for the cluster master while opening connections? That would explain this kind of behaviour.

Comment: (Mariadb tracker link is https://jira.mariadb.org/projects/CONJ/issues/)

Comment: can you execute a "show processlist" to list those multiple connections and their states ?

Comment: @DiegoDupin, thanks for your help. I've edited the question providing more details about the issue including the connections status.

Comment: @JavierCane were you ever able to figure this out? It's been a few years, and I'm running into this same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the "aurora" keyword, driver , under the hood, create 2 connections:

- a connection to the primary server,
- a connection to one of the replicas if any.

The goal is always to save resources on the main server. Generally, only one pool is configured. The driver then uses the connection to the primary / replica according to [Connection.setReadOnly] [1].

When you have separate "write" / "read" pools, using the configuration "failover" will solve your issue: Driver will use only one real connection.
This way, there will be no "wasted" connection.

Failover will then be handled differently, but with the same results (for example, a query not in a transaction that is to be sent to a replica that just crashed will not directly use the primary connection as when using the "aurora" configuration, the driver will recreate a new connection to another replicas before executing the query).

Comment: 1. According to your comment, then it wouldn't make too much sense to have multiple Aurora Reader instances, would it? I mean, if the driver will only choose one of the Reader replicas, it will not be distributing the load between the different replicas. It only will be useful in case of a replica failover :S

2. According to your suggestion, we should set the URL schema for the master as `jdbc:mysql:aurora://` and the one for the slave as `jdbc:mysql:failover://` ([full example](https://pastebin.com/ieyn5fkH)), have I understood you well?

Thanks!

Comment: if you use the  "master" pooling configuration only to connect to master i.e , never switch a connection using connection.setReadOnly() or component that will do that like Spring @Transaction(readonly=true), then you can use "jdbc:mysql:failover://". This will avoid to create a slave connection for each connection to master.

Comment: The replicat connection is selected randomly among the valid hosts. Thereafter, all statements will run on that database server until the connection will be closed (or fails). So with 60 connections to replicas with a cluster of 3 replicas, their will be roughly 20 connections to each replicas

Comment: I just understood your point. My mistake was thinking about connection pools as groups of connections to the very same Reader. In the scenario you just described, the slave connection pool would be formed based on connections to different random Readers, so it will actually balance the load between them. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding to the master connection pool: 1. So if I point out to the `cluster-name.cluster-xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` URL with the `failover:` config, it will always open the connection against the Writer? 2. In that case, will we be missing any other connector feature for Aurora?

Answer (score 1):

Once you get past several dozen *active* connections, the database starts stumbling over itself.  It is better to throttle the connections in the client instead of assuming you have infinite bandwidth to accept connections in Aurora.

Comment: Sure :)
The thing is that if I don't add the `aurora:` part to the JDBC URL schema, HikariCP (the DB connection pool) properly manages the number of connections in the client. But as soon as I add the `aurora:` part, it doesn't do that.

In case this is a bug, how can I report it to the MariaDB JDBC connector? They don't have the GitHub "Issues" enabled in their repo :/ https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-j/