# Does MariaDB Connector/J 2.6.x create connections to both master and slave with Aurora?

Tags: mysql, playframework, mariadb, hikaricp, amazon-aurora

According to other answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020489/db-connections-increase-after-setting-aurora-in-mariadb-connector), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163044/mariadb-connector-j-aurora-fast-failover-implemantation)), as well as some documentation in the [mariadb-connector-j repo](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-j/blob/caad0f1682062251595978a454a37b50a3515c40/documentation/failover_loop.creole), the consensus seems to be:

> On a master/slave cluster, driver will use underlying 2 connections:
> one to a master instance, one to a slave instance.

> A "connection" to aurora mean 2 underlying connection to instances:
> one to master, one to slave. Driver will use the underlying connection
> to master or slave according to Connection.setReadonly().

> When using the "aurora" keyword, driver , under the hood, create 2
> connections: a connection to the primary server, a connection to one
> of the replicas if any. The goal is always to save resources on the
> main server. Generally, only one pool is configured. The driver then
> uses the connection to the primary / replica according to
> [Connection.setReadOnly]

However, I am trying this for myself and do not see this behavior with MariaDB Connector/J 2.6.2 (in a Play 2.8.x application, which uses HikariCP as the connection pool). I created a new MySQL Aurora cluster (with a master and read-replica) and modified my test application to connect to this cluster with a HikariCP pool that's configured at a fixed size of 8 connections, using the cluster endpoint url as follows:

```
"jdbc:mysql:aurora://test.cluster-abcdefg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/test"
```

From what I can see in the logs, as well as the attached image from the RDS web dashboard's monitoring tab, once the application starts up, the master goes to 8 connections (blue line) and the read-replica has 0 connections (orange line). This seems to be contrary to all the above points that, under the hood, the driver makes 2 underlying connections and chooses between them based on the status of a given `Connection`'s read-only property.

[image: RDS web dashboard connections monitor]

The Play configuration for this connection is as follows:

```
  test {
    driver = org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    url = "jdbc:mysql:aurora://test.cluster-abcdefg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/test"

    hikaricp {
      autoCommit = false
      readOnly = false
    }
  }
```

If I instead configure the connection like:

```
  test {
    driver = org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    url = "jdbc:mysql:aurora://test.cluster-abcdefg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/test"

    hikaricp {
      autoCommit = true
      readOnly = true
    }
  }
```

then I do see connections made to both the master and read-replica:

[image: RDS web dashboard monitoring 2]

Please help me understand this behavior.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have separate write and read pools. The write pool would always point to the master, and the read pool would always point to a read replica (assuming one exists). I want to avoid dual underlying connections, as the `readOnly` setting is configured at the pool level and will never change on a given `Connection` during its lifetime. How can I achieve this?

Additionally, I would like to know whether I am expected to use the `autoReconnect` parameter when specifying the `aurora` failover mode. Does the value of that parameter matter with the `aurora` failover mode?

Comment: In MySQL flavor of aurora this is the default behavior, separate read\write pools .
Why use mariaDB?

Comment: @Shachaf.Gortler I am using the MariaDB Connector/J (with MySQL flavor of Aurora) because that connector is aware of Aurora and has Aurora-specific features around failover scenarios and balancing connections amongst read-replicas. AWS explicitly recommends the use of this Java connector in the "Aurora Database Administrator's Handbook" - https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/RDS/amazon-aurora-connection-management-handbook.pdf

Comment: I was under the impression that the MariaDB JDBC driver with Aurora support will use the read-replica for a fresh connection as soon as you mark the connection as read-only (`conn.setReadOnly(true);` It does not do this automatically when you use a SELECT statement, you need to explicitly mark the connection as read-only.